# WPFcheckbox: add click event additionally to checked/unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

In WPF, I want to open a dialog the fist time the user clicks on a `CheckBox` - some kind of warning, if he really wants to enable this option. The event will be handled in code-behind.

Something like this could be possible:

```xaml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Something.Enabled}"
          PreviewMouseDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
<!-- or: -->
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Something.Enabled}"
          Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
```

I additionally want to bind the `CheckBox` checked and unchecked event to the `IsChecked` property like in the example above.

Comment: can you please share the exact requirement and your tried codes?

Comment: Why not just put the 'warning' near (top or bottom of) the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any kind of confirmation dialog will stop the `CheckBox` from being clicked, you would have to set `Something.Enabled` yourself. Setting the `CheckBox.IsChecked` in code behind would simply destroy your binding.

You could place the confirmation in the ViewModel (in the setter of `Something.Enabled`) or like this:

```
private bool _confirmed;

private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(!_confirmed)
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) 
        == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        _confirmed = true;
        Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add new Boolean flag that hold the value, whether the DialogBox has been already displayed.